# Get saturday date for the given input date using bash script

Tags: bash, shell

By using the below command, it will return the last saturday date.

```
date +"%b-%d-%Y" -d "last saturday"
Sep-01-2018
```

I want to pass input date as parameter, which should return the last saturday's date in bash script.

```
Aug-08-2018  -----> Aug-04-2018
Jun-04-2018  -----> Jun-02-2018
```

Comment: what `date` implementation are you using ?

Comment: last saturday's u mean if you pass 2018-08-31 give you all saturdays on Aug right ?

Comment: Nope.. It should return only the last saturday date for the input date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get a negative number that will be the number of days to subtract.  We use 13, because Saturday is 6, and `6 + 7 = 13`.  This will get us the Saturday one or two weeks ahead.  Then we modulo 7, to ensure it is NEXT Saturday, then subtract 7 to make it LAST Saturday.  Then we put that diff into the date string:

```
$ date_str="Aug-08-2018"
$ diff=$(( (13 - $(date +"%u" -d ${date_str})) % 7 - 7))
$ date -d "${date_str} ${diff} days"
Sat Aug  4 00:00:00 EDT 2018
```